# ¿Cómo heredar un evento Click en los nodos hijos?

Tags: javascript, eventos

tengo un problema con un evento click que estoy creando

```
var o = {
 categorias: document.querySelectorAll(".categorias-tmc"),
 productos: document.querySelectorAll("#productos-tmc div"),
 cat: null,

}

var m = {

 inicio: function(){
  for(var i = 0; i < o.categorias.length;i++){

    o.categorias[i].addEventListener("click", m.seleccion)
  }
 },

 seleccion: function(e){
    o.cat = e.target.getAttribute("cat"),
    console.log(o.cat)
 }

}

m.inicio();
```

El problema es que en el HTML dentro de el div tengo un img que al dar clic no reproduce el código. Gracias.

Hola, que tal gracias a todos por sus respuestas, a continuacion el codigo html y css

```
<div>
    <div class="categorias-tmc column one-sixth" cat="alimenticios">
        <img src="" alt="productos alimenticios">
        <h2>PRODUCTOS ALIMENTICIOS</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="categorias-tmc column one-sixth" cat="belleza">
        <img src="" alt="belleza y salud">
        <h2>BELLEZA Y SALUD</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="categorias-tmc column one-sixth" cat="libros">
        <img src="" alt="libros y gadgets">
        <h2>LIBROS Y GADGETS</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="categorias-tmc column one-sixth" cat="accesorios">
        <img src="" alt="ropa y accesorios">
        <h2>ROPA Y ACCESORIOS</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="categorias-tmc column one-sixth" cat="artesanales">
        <img src="" alt="productos artesanales">
        <h2>PRODUCTOS ARTESANALES</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="categorias-tmc column one-sixth">
        <img src="" alt="regalos">
        <h2>OH!!!</h2>
    </div>
</div>

.categorias-tmc {
    box-shadow: 0 0 6px #0000003b;
    background: white;
    transition: 0.2s ease;
    min-height: 230px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.categorias-tmc:hover {
    transform: scale(1.1);
}
.categorias-tmc h2 {
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 18px;
}
.categorias-tmc img {
    width: 100px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.categorias-tmc img {
    width: 100px;
    margin: 30px 0;
}
.categorias-tmc:nth-child(odd) h2 {
    color: #53c9ff;
}
.categorias-tmc:nth-child(even) h2 {
    color: #451490;
}
.no-margin-h .one-sixth.column {
    width: 16.666%;
}
```

disculpen si estoy usando la plataforma mal realmente soy nuevo, un saludo !

Comment: Hola Sebastián, podrías compartir tu código HTML?

Comment: Hay varias cosas que pueden producir este error,usualmente problemas de css,
como que el div que tiene el evento tenga tamaño 0x0 a pesar de que sus hijos si tengan tamaño y sean visibles, puedes verificar si este es tu caso revisando en el inspector si el elemento padre tiene tamaño 0, puedes solucionar eso especificando el tamaño por css o definiendo la propiedad overflow de css, esto a veces resuelve el problema. Te recomindo que publiques el codigo html y css que te da el problema a fin de que podamos replicarlo y darte una mejor respuesta.

Comment: Brother, gracias por tomar tiempo para leer las preguntas de la comunidad, pero como no estás proporcionando una respuesta... lo mejor es añadir un comentario ;)

Comment: :( lo intente pero el sistema no me deja por tener menos de 50pts de preputacion, soy nuevo, por lo que para tener acceso a comentar tenia que dar una respuesta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cuando declaras el listener sobre los elementos con clase `categorias-tmc` el listener efectivamente se propaga a todos los hijos.

Sin embargo, hay que tener en cuenta que el evento que se envía al handler tiene como propiedad `target` al elemento que gatilla la acción. Vale decir:

- Click en la imagen
- Se gatilla m.seleccion(e)
- e.target es la imagen
- la imagen no tiene atributo `cat`
- KABOOM

Pero no todo está perdido. Cuando declaras un listener, la variable `this` dentro del handler apunta al emento original sobre el cual se declaró el listener:

```
var m = {
      inicio: function () {
        for (var i = 0; i < o.categorias.length; i++) {
          o.categorias[i].addEventListener("click", m.seleccion)
        }
      },

      seleccion: function (e) {
        o.cat = this.getAttribute("cat"),
        console.log(o.cat)
      }
 }
```

Prueba esa versión.

```js
var o = {
      categorias: document.querySelectorAll(".categorias-tmc"),
      productos: document.querySelectorAll("#productos-tmc div"),
      cat: null,

    }

    var m = {

      inicio: function () {
        for (var i = 0; i < o.categorias.length; i++) {

          o.categorias[i].addEventListener("click", m.seleccion)
        }
      },

      seleccion: function (e) {
        o.cat = this.getAttribute("cat"),
          console.log(o.cat)
      }

    }

    m.inicio();
```

```css
.categorias-tmc {
      box-shadow: 0 0 6px #0000003b;
      background: white;
      transition: 0.2s ease;
      min-height: 50px;
      cursor: pointer;
      float: left;
    }

    .categorias-tmc:hover {
      transform: scale(1.1);
    }

    .categorias-tmc h2 {
      font-size: 15px;
      line-height: 15px;
      margin: 5px;
      padding: 5px;
    }

    .categorias-tmc img {
      width: 100px;
      margin: 5px 0;
    }

    .categorias-tmc:nth-child(odd) h2 {
      color: #53c9ff;
    }

    .categorias-tmc:nth-child(even) h2 {
      color: #451490;
    }

    .no-margin-h .one-sixth.column {
      width: 49%;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="no-margin-h" style="width: 600px;margin:0 auto;">
      <div class="categorias-tmc column one-sixth" cat="alimenticios">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x65/ff0000" alt="productos alimenticios">
        <h2>PRODUCTOS ALIMENTICIOS</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="categorias-tmc column one-sixth" cat="belleza">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x65/336699" alt="belleza y salud">
        <h2>BELLEZA Y SALUD</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="categorias-tmc column one-sixth" cat="libros">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x65/00ff00" alt="libros y gadgets">
        <h2>LIBROS Y GADGETS</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="categorias-tmc column one-sixth" cat="accesorios">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x65/0000ff" alt="ropa y accesorios">
        <h2>ROPA Y ACCESORIOS</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="categorias-tmc column one-sixth" cat="artesanales">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x65/ff00ff" alt="productos artesanales">
        <h2>PRODUCTOS ARTESANALES</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="categorias-tmc column one-sixth">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x65/00ffff" alt="regalos">
        <h2>OH!!!</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
```